Shower arm replacement and lost shower pipe behind the wall
I was replacing the shower head arm in my shower and when I unscrewed the shower head arm the pipe behind the wall that it's attached to disappeared. How do I locate this thing so I can connect the new shower head arm?

Welcome to SE! The female fitting should still be there in the wall. It may have moved a bit when you disconnected the old shower arm. Shine a light into the opening. It should give you some idea of how far out of position it might be. You may have to loop a length of wire around it and gently pull it back into position to get the shower arm started.

I can't see a thing when I shine a light in the hole.

is the wall tiled?   What is on the other side of the wall?    This is a pretty serious issue as it isn't common and might be a pain to fix.

I hope you have access to the other side of the wall!

Take a coat hanger and put a hook in it. Stick it in the hole and rotate it to see if it will hook on to the pipe.

Try a USB camera. Some are the diameter of a pencil and designed for looking in tight places. Most have their own light source. See https://www.amazon.com/bore-cam/s?k=bore+cam for examples.
